# Why is this array always empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, core-image

I'm trying to figure out how do I get an image from the user's camera roll and run some Core Image operations on it (detect faces). I'm able to successfully load the image into a uiimageview, but for some reason I'm not able to use that image to detect faces using core image. The array in question is the last bit of code, this array should hold CIFaceFeatures, but it keeps coming up empty. I've tried using different images but still won't work. Any ideas?

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
UIImage *image =  [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
self.facePicture.image = image;

CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.facePicture.image.CGImage];

CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image]; //***features array is empty
NSLog(@"array count is %i",features.count); //returns 0
//Code continues with face detection stuff

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following line

```
UIImage *image =  [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

to:

```
UIImage *image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

The important part is the changing from using `@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"` to using `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`. The reason for this is that `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` is declared as the following:

```
extern NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage;
```

Elsewhere, in Apple's actual implementation file, will be something like this where `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` is actually defined:

```
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = @"someStringLiteral";
```

The actual string literal value that Apple chose to use could be anything, and does not necessarily have to be the same as the variable's name. By calling `[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]`, you were basically making the assumption that `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` **is** actually `@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"`, which need not necessarily be the case.

I'm hypothesizing that the original line resulted in a returned value of `nil`, meaning no object was found for the key `@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"`. If that `image` is then `nil`, the rest of the code would basically "silently fail". If you follow the code through, it would basically equate to doing something like this:

```
self.facePicture.image = nil;

CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:NULL]; // likely returns nil

NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:nil]; //***features array is empty
NSLog(@"array count is %i", features.count); //returns 0
```